# PHP - POO Diferencia entre llamadas usando de literales o referencias

Tags: php, poo

En PHP podemos tener una clase como la siguiente:

```
class Test {

    public static function xxx() {
        //hacer algo
    }

    public static function yyy() {
        //hacer algo
    }

    public static function zzz() {
        //hacer algo
    }


    public static function mi_test() {

        //Llamada literal al método de la propia clase
        Test::xxx();

        //Llamadas usando referencias
        self::yyy();
        self::zzz();
    }

} //class
```

Llamar a los métodos de una u otra forma parece que funciona igual, ¿existen diferencias?

Yo he observado, por ejemplo, que con las llamadas literales es más fácil localizar errores, debidos a llamadas erroneas, en caso de reestructurar / refactorizar las clases y mover métodos, aunque no encontre preferencias por una u otra en listas de buenas prácticas, entonces ¿se recomienda una las formas sobre la otra, en qué casos y por qué?

Answer (score 0):

Hay una pequeña diferencia: `self::` reenvía llamadas estáticas, mientras que `className::` no. Esto sólo tiene importancia para los [Enlaces estáticos en tiempo de ejecución](http://php.net/lsb) en PHP 5.3+.

En llamadas estáticas, PHP 5.3+ recuerda la clase inicialmente llamada. Usando `className::` hace que PHP "olvide" este valor (es decir, lo restablece a className), mientras `self::` lo preserva.

Esto se puede entender considerando el siguiente código:

<kbd>[**VER DEMO**](http://rextester.com/FEUI89743)</kbd>

```
<?php 

class A 
{
    static function foo() 
    {
        echo get_called_class()."\n";
    }
}

class B extends A 
{
    static function bar() 
    {
        self::foo();
    }
    static function baz() 
    {
        B::foo();
    }
}

class C extends B 
{
}

C::bar(); //C
C::baz(); //B    
?>
```

**Resultado**

```
C
B
```

Ver [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3481105/5587982) en SO en Inglés.

Comment: Si 
**Usando className:: hace que PHP "olvide" este valor (es decir, lo restablece a className), mientras self:: lo preserva**
Entiendo que self::, por lo pronto empreará más memoria. Lo que no se si las llamadas literales requieren que el sistema busque la clase, aunque sea la misma, mientras que de usar self:: esto se produce de forma automática.